# Из-за HTML тегов в записи Wordpress поехала верстка

Tags: wordpress

Подскажите, пожалуйста.

У меня в теле статьи содержатся HTML теги. И они сломали верстку не только статьи, но и сайдбара и футера.

https://qaa-engineer.ru/kakie-tegi-ispolzuyutsya-v-html-dlya-oformleniya-tekstovogo-soderzhimogo/

Может есть плагин какой-нибудь, чтобы это исправить?
Или как-то можно починить с помощью functions.php?

Comment: Добавьте вывод значений через htmlspecialchars.